# Rails find and replace instances of attribute after rename_column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, grep, rename

I've looked around and haven't found an elegant solution for this, so I figured I'd ask.

I am in the middle of refactoring a couple database tables to keep my naming scheme continuous throughout the application.  My process is currently this:

Create a migration to rename a bunch of columns:

```
class RenameSomeAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :some_tables, :old_name, :new_name
  end
end
```

Save a record of the instances of :old_name before I replace them in the rest of my code.  (Optional)

```
$ grep -r old_name app lib spec >> find-replace-history.txt
```

Find and replace the string in my models, views, controllers, javascripts, stylesheets, specs, rake tasks etc.

```
$ grep -rl old_name app lib spec | xargs sed -r 's/old_name/new_name/g'
```

However, this method is only useful when I'm working with attribute names that are only specific to the table that I am adjusting.  For more general attribute names (:name, :description etc), I am forced to manually edit files to avoid replacing the wrong table's attribute.

Is there a better tool that I should be using that would help me find every instance of the attribute, and only replace it when the attributes applies to a specific table?  I don't mind adjusting the assets separately, because they won't know which table I am referring to.  However, Rails should be able to determine if a given attribute pertains to the table that I am adjusting in all of my ruby files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such a tool. You will have to do it manually as you're doing now. However, if the old attribute name is still in use somewhere, there's a way to prevent that from breaking your code.

In `SomeTable` model, implement `method_missing` method

```
def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
  if method.to_s == "old_name"
    self.new_name
  else
    super
  end
end
```

To understand how `method_missing` works, check out [this article](http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html) which will recommend that you should also implement `respond_to?` method.

You might want to add the following to the `method_missing` method above (Add it after the `if` statement).

```
Rails.logger.debug caller.join("\n")
```

This would show the code that still references the old attribute name. Hope this helps.